# How to force to 0 the intercept of a weighted regression?

Tags: r, linear-regression, weighted

I need to do a regression weighting the errors that I already have in my dataframe for both variables. I need both the outcomes and the plot, but I need to set the intercept equal to 0. Do you have any idea on how to perform it? Thanks in advance

I'm using the package 'bfsl' but the problem is that I can not modify the parameter of 'y' in order to force the regression intercept to the origin.

Comment: I don't know about that package, but the typical syntax is something like `lm(y ~ 0 + x)`

Comment: Yes but with the common 'lm()' function I think is not possible to do the weighted regression